# Get current date in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, date, thymeleaf

How can I print current date (and time, eventually) from Thymeleaf?
I'm trying these functions:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates
but I can't get them work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try with this:

```
${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')}
```

will be created a `java.util.Date()` object then formatted as you prefer.

---

**Using the `#calendars` utility object**

This is an alternative method:

```
${#calendars.format(#calendars.createNow(), 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')}
```

the result will be the same.

Comment: With `Java8TimeDialect` there's now `#temporals` as well.

Answer (score 7):

This one works fine for me:

`${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(),'YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm')}`

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` is going to be processed by the `#dates` utility.
The new `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate` classes are going to be processed by the `#temporals` utility.

***Set the format***:

```
<p th:text="${#dates.format(standardDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></p>
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDateTime, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></p>
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(localDate, 'MM-yyyy')}"></p>
```

Where you have to ***sent it to a view*** as following:

```
model.addAttribute("standardDate", new Date());
model.addAttribute("localDateTime", LocalDateTime.now());
model.addAttribute("localDate", LocalDate.now());
```

Formatting the `LocalDate` is only possible if we will specify only the particular date fields, skipping the time fields.

***Output result***:

```
24-05-2019 21:57
24-05-2019 21:57
24-05-2019
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to get the current date and time in thymeleaf is using,

```
${execInfo.now}
```

> The current date and time (`${execInfo.now}`), a Calendar object
>   corresponding to the moment the template engine started its execution
>   for this template.

You can create an WebContext to modify the context variables,

```
WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, servletContext, request.getLocale());
```

When the context is created, it creates a object which holds the two values for the template engine. The object name is `execInfo`. The two variables are `templateName` and `now`. These variables can be accessed across anywhere in the templates.

If you need to format the date format you can do like this,

```
WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, servletContext, request.getLocale());
ctx.setVariable("today", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Example:

```
Current time : <div th:text="${execInfo.now.time}">Wed Feb 10 13:55:58 IST 2016</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works :

```
<b th:text="${#execInfo.now.time}"></b>
```

Comment: Would be nice to see an explanation of why this works, e.g., what is "execInfo"?

Comment: More details about execInfo in thymeleaf docs https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#execution-info and apidocs https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/ExecutionInfo.html